# How to look about transtion is complated?

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc, blockexplorer

I'm trying to build my own blockexplorer, and to this i need to update a single transtion with confrims, my problems is i can't see how meny confrims there shut be and when my transtion is 100% complated.

i'm using RPC and bitcoin logic but what i'm working on is a multi-currency explorer based on bitcoin rpc syntax.

i use gettransaction (hash) and in this i can only se how many confrims, what do i wrong here?

i know i can say 6 confirms+ will be 100% complated, but the confirms still get bigger after 6 confirms, so i need to know when i shut stop to update my transtion on my blockexplorer project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let your explorer display the number of blocks confirmed.

As [satoshi explains in section 11 of the whitepaper](https://bitcoin.org/bitcoin.pdf), a bitcoin transaction is never 100% final, but only the probability of it being not-final decreases with every confirmation. What probability of non-finality is good enough?

People could have any use-case so let people decide for themselves. Most want 6 confirmations safety to buy a car, some want 1 confirmation to buy coffee (and there are people like Roger Ver who want no confirmation!).

Comment: Thanks very much, its make sens and i can work with that :)